# printing php array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a question, I'm making a website that display quests from a pre defined php numbered array, when I try to echo the array in direct, the result is correct

```
QuestionSQL= "<?php echo $QArray[1][0]; ?>";
```

but when I try to assign variable as the index the result is empty

```
ChoiceSQL= '<?php echo $QArray[' + trialNumber +'][' + QuestNumber + ']; ?>';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You do understand that PHP is back end and JavaScript is front end and they are not interchangeable right?  You need to `echo` out your JavaScript variable **from** `php`.

Comment: thank you bro, I did that and it worked
thank you very much for your help and time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot evaluate JavaScript variables in a PHP script (which is the *whole* part between `<?php` and `?>`. PHP does not execute JavaScript.

In this case a solution is to let PHP produce the whole array as part of the JavaScript code, so that JavaScript has the array to play with:

```
var quests = <?php echo json_encode($QArray) ?>;

// ...
var trialNumber = 1;
var questNumber = 0;
var choiceSQL = quests[trialNumber][questNumber];
```